# Newbie approach to understand generalized continuum hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, infinity

There is this theorem that size of power set constructed from infinite set is "more" infinite than the previous set:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\aleph_0 &= |\mathbb{N}| \\
\aleph_{n+1} &= 2^{\aleph_n} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

I always understood the real numbers as $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}$, where $a \in \mathbb{N}$ is the part "prior" to comma, and the $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ is part "past" the comma. This seems to make it possible to construct any numbers, be it rational, irrational or whatever. (Correct me if I'm wrong.) This kind of reasoning, however, seems to clash with GCH. Namely, while $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{Z}| = \aleph_0$, my reasoning implies that $\mathbb{N}^2 \equiv \mathbb{R}$, which according to GCH is false, because $\aleph_1 \neq \aleph_0^2$ and $\aleph_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

I try to imagine real numbers as a power set of natural numbers, but I fail.

My question is: why my reasoning that $\mathbb{R} \equiv \mathbb{N}^2$ is wrong? And how to comprehend the idea that $2^\mathbb{N} \equiv \mathbb{R}$, i.e. how to use power set of natural numbers to obtain/construct real numbers?

As a hobbyist I'd like illustrative, practical examples the most instead of going into raw stuff.

Comment: The part "past" the comma can have infinite number of digits (e.g. 3.333333....) so is not in $Z$. To understand $2^N = R$ think binary: With $x = 0.a_1a_2...$, how many $x$ (real numbers in $[0,1]$) can we make? Well, there are $2$ choices for each digits making a total of $2^{1+1+1+1...} = 2^{N}$.

Comment: And, for every non-empty set (where things get strange), finite or not, the powerset has greater cardinality than the original set.

Comment: But $\mathbb{Z}$ contains uncountably many numbers in the way that whatever number I could think of is already there. Does it not mean that $b = 333...$ also belong in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @rr: Sorry, not clear on your point.

Comment: I was referring to first part of @Winther's comment.

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ absolutely does not contain uncountably many numbers. "$333...$" is not an integer. Recall that the definition of countable is "can be put in bijection with $\mathbb N$" and there's an easy such bijection.

Comment: One way of seeing that it is not an integer is that the sum diverges, i.e., goes to $\infty$, unlike the case when you go in the opposite direction.

Comment: Spot on! @MikeMiller and Winther's comments answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know my comments did nothing for you.

Comment: @user9980 The last one was useful, but by the time I read it I already understood my mistakes.

Comment: @user99680 Regarding your first comment: No need to qualify with "non-empty": $|\emptyset| = 0$ but $|\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)| = 1$. :)

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: I just wanted to avoid having to present arguments to this effect; arguments involving the empty set can get bizarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is this theorem that size of power set constructed from infinite
>   set is "more" infinite than the previous set.

Yes, its called [Cantor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem). But it doesn't say that $2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \aleph_{\alpha+1}$. That's a (famous) strictly stronger statement called [GCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis), and it is independent of the usual axioms of set theory (most set theorists believe that *if* there is a true universe of sets, then GCH is probably false in that universe. However, the usual axioms can neither prove nor refute GCH.)

Cantor's theorem is the weaker statement that $2^{\aleph_\alpha} > \aleph_\alpha$. Actually, it really has nothing to do with the $\aleph$ numbers, so the best statement of Cantor's theorem is surely: "$2^\kappa>\kappa$ for any cardinal number $\kappa$." Contrary to GCH, Cantor's theorem is more-or-less uncontroversial, except among certain laypeople.

> I always understood the real numbers as $(a,b)∈\mathbb{N×Z}$, where $a∈\mathbb{N}$ is the part "prior" to comma, and the $b∈\mathbb{Z}$ is part "past" the comma.

This makes no sense to me. Are you sure you're not mixing up the real numbers with the rational numbers? I often think of $\mathbb{Q}$ as being a quotient of $\mathbb{(N\setminus\{0\})×Z}.$

> My reasoning implies that $\mathbb{N}^2≡\mathbb{R}$.

As you correctly surmise, this is incorrect, by Cantor's theorem. If you were to prove the truth of $\mathbb{N}^2≡\mathbb{R}$, you would prove the entirety of modern set theory logically inconsistent. (Needless to say, I don't think this is very likely.)

> My question is: why my reasoning that $\mathbb{N}^2≡\mathbb{R}$ is wrong?

Well we'd be happy to play with "find the error" game with your proof (this can be quite an instructive exercise), but you haven't really given us a proof!

**My verdict.** This site works best when you have already have a basic understanding of how things "fit together" in the branch of math you're asking questions about. Since your question is predicated on more than one misconception,  I think you should find yourself a good book to learn the basics, even if you're just an interested hobbyist. Trying to learn the basics purely by reading wikipedia and/or asking question at math.stackexchange is a crappy approach to learning the fundamentals; trust me, I've tried it at least twice.

I'd recommend Goldrei's set theory for a readable introduction. If you work through an introductory set theory book (asking questions on this site as they arise, of course), things will be a lot clearer, and the site will be more useful to you.